# Unable to free diskspace by removing files and not restarting the computer (hibernation possible)

Tags: filesystem, disk-usage, delete, df, du

I have a similar problem to the one mentioned here: [Unable to free up space in df](https://askubuntu.com/questions/903075/unable-to-free-up-space-in-df) but I can not reboot (I have important data in the memory).

The output of `df -h /` is:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2        47G   45G     0 100% /
```

which would be fine unless it stayed like that after I removed ca 13G of data.

Cumulated size of all files in `/dev/sda2` available from `/` is a half of its capacity:

```
$ sudo du -xhd 0 /
23G     /
```

I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653096/how-to-free-inode-usage#9387415 but it definitely is not a problem with inodes:

```
$ df -hi /
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda2        3.0M  535K  2.5M   18% /
```

How can I free the space without restarting the computer (however I shall be able to hibernate it since I have more swap area than physical RAM)?

One more comment: to save the data anywhere I need to be able to write to `/tmp/` (ask NumPy developers why) which is at `/dev/sda2` filesystem.

Comment: Take a usb drive, mount it in `/tmp`, save your data in `/tmp` and you're good to go – or did I misunderstand something here?

Comment: That may do the trick (unless there are other issueas  I do not know about yet). Thanks!

Comment: @dessert sure, but I will try it as soon as:
1. I find a suitable usb drive,
2. NumPy finishes writing the main array of data into plain `*.npy` file (I ripped it out from the data object; now the disk fragmentation kicked in :-/).

Comment: @dessert both salvage methods worked. :-)

Comment: Excellent! I'll write an answer for you to accept so that we can close here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Find a drive, e.g. a USB stick, that has enough space for your data and plug it in
2. Get its device partition name using `lsblk`, I use `/dev/sdb1` as an example here.
3. It your drive got automounted first unmount it with `sudo umount /dev/sdb1`, then mount it in `/tmp` using

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /tmp
   ```
4. Save your data to `/tmp`
5. Unmount your drive using

   ```
   sudo umount /dev/sdb1
   ```
6. Free space as explained in the links you provided.

Comment: the answer to be complete needs to mention that the whole problem was of the kind "chicken and egg". The diskspace was freed when I killed the IPython console. It seems NumPy tried to allocate big temporary file, failed, not disposed the diskspace. Then each time I tried to delete some files and store my data the sequence repeated.
Similar problem is solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36349961/4879688

Comment: @abukaj I don't totally get it and therefore hesitate to add it to my answer, but I think your comment suffices to make it clear. Thank you!

Comment: Well, it is you who helped me to save my data. :)

Comment: @abukaj You're very welcome! :)